# Disable mouse right click in PDF

Tags: pdf, iframe

I am try to load an uploaded PDF file to my view file with an `<iframe>` tag, How can i disable the mouse right click in that specific `<iframe>` tag

My code is like this:-

```
<iframe id="your_iframe_id" src="http://localhost/employee/assets/documents/1582002009.pdf#toolbar=0&navpanes=0&scrollbar=0" onload="injectJS()" readonly="true"  style="width:1000px; height:600px;" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Comment: ermm your code isnt in the post ?

Answer (score -1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function disableContextMenu()
{
window.frames["your i frame id"].document.oncontextmenu = function(){alert("No way!"); return false;};   
// Or use this
// document.getElementById("your i frame id").contentWindow.document.oncontextmenu 
= function(){alert("No way!"); return false;};;    
 }  
</script>
```

dont remember call this function too. if its not working tell me

Comment: Hi,

I have called this disableContextMenu() in my iframe onload

<iframe id="myframe" src="http://localhost/employee/assets/documents/1582002009.pdf#toolbar=0&navpanes=0&scrollbar=0" oncontextmenu="return false" onload="disableContextMenu()" readonly="true"  style="width:1000px; height:600px;" frameborder="0"></iframe>


After that i have written your function in footer. the controll is in function .. but the mouse right click is not disabled..

Comment: Iframe is load, while i clicking a view button.. my project was in codeigniter. In onload function i just put a alert() its working in onload function. But this line document.getElementById("myframe").contentWindow.document.oncontextmenu = function(){alert("No way!"); return false;} was not executing i think

Comment: ok you cant put any function or anything which is not load with dom. if press the button and then load somthing that is not part of dom object

Comment: if you want to check this put alert on i frame it doesnt work. it cant all alert.but you want to doing somthing then usr on() event on event work if element is not part of dome at runtime.....

Comment: I can't clearly understand what your are saying ...can you please give me your contact email id.. i can share my project logins.. or can you send an example on on event..? you mean jquery live event.? like on mouse over etc..

Comment: can you please ping me on this email address - ajeesh.cordial@gmail.com

Comment: i send message on your gmail please check with hangout

Comment: sorry i didnt get your mail... ajeesh.cordial@gmail.com or ajeeshteepee@gmail.com

Comment: please send me your email address

Comment: @AjeeshTP idrishmakda52.im@gmail.com